# C#: Do I always instantiate a new reference type variable?

Tags: c#

Which of these two cases is the most correct?  This case where the rxBytes variable is only declared?

```
private void ParseRxData(RxMessage rxMessage) {
    List<byte> rxBytes;
    rxBytes = rxMessage.LengthBytes;
    rxBytes.AddRange(rxMessage.Payload);
    /* Do stuff with 'rxBytes' variable */
}
```

Or this case where the rxBytes varible is instantiated?

```
private void ParseRxData(RxMessage rxMessage) {
    var rxBytes = new List<byte>;
    rxBytes = rxMessage.LengthBytes;
    rxBytes.AddRange(rxMessage.Payload);
    /* Do stuff with 'rxBytes' variable */
}
```

In short, is it necessary to instantiate a variable when it's assigned a value immediately after it's been declared?

I'm a fairly new C#/OOP programmer, so I apologize if I'm not using terminology correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In short, is it necessary to instantiate a variable when it's assigned a value immediately after it's been declared?

No - in fact if you initialize `rxBytes` to a new `List<byte>`, then overwrite the variable with `rxMessage.LengthBytes`, then the list you created is never used and will be garbage collected.  You seem to assign it a `List<byte>` just so you can use `var` which is unnecessary.  Your first code block is the correct approach.

You can also just do

```
var rxBytes = rxMessage.LengthBytes;
```

But functionally there's no difference between declaring the variable on one line and assigning it a value on another.

> Is there any way to set the equal sign "by value"?

Well for reference types the "value" *is* a reference, but if you just want the new variable to reference a *copy* of the list you can do

```
var rxBytes = new List<byte>(rxMessage.LengthBytes);
```

Comment: Hmm...  This wasn't as straight forward as I thought.  It seems using either block causes a problem.  Since the rxMessage.LengthBytes is a List<byte> property in the RxMessage class, it seems like C# copies the reference to rxMessage.LengthBytes to rxBytes.  So when adding rxMessage.Payload to rxBytes, I'm also adding them to rxMessage.LengthBytes.  Is there any way to set the equal sign "by value"?  Otherwise I have to use rxBytes.AddRange(rxMessage.LengthBytes), in which case I also have to initialize rxBytes with "new" first.

Answer (score 1):

The following is entirely legal syntax:

```
List<byte> rxBytes = rxMessage.LengthBytes;
```

It's not the instantiation that is required, just an assignment.

When you create a new object using the `new` keyword, you are allocating memory for that object. In your case, however, you allocate memory for an object and hand a reference to the object to your variable, then immediately assign that variable to point at another object. That first object immediately becomes orphaned and, eventually, garbage collected.

So really, what you are asking if you can do is not only allowed, it is a better practice for responsible programming.